# Nativescript RadListView Scroll to Bottom with footer

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui, radlistview

I am using RadListView and am trying to programmatically scroll to the bottom of the list. I am able to use the `scrollToIndex()` function to scroll to the last element in the list, but my list has a footer and I need to scroll past that as well. I can't figure out a clean way to do that besides scrolling to the last element and then do a `scrollWithAmount()` with the height of the footer. That way doesn't work the greatest and I feel like there should be a better way.

[Here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=mbMo8E&v=3) is a Playground showing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scroll to the bottom most of the RadListView, you may simply calculate it's height and scroll with amount.

```
    let to;
    if (this.radList.ios) {
        const collectionView = this.radList.nativeViewProtected.collectionView;
        to = Math.max(0, collectionView.contentSize.height - collectionView.bounds.size.height);
    } else {
        to = layout.toDevicePixels(this.radList.getMeasuredHeight());
    }
    this.radList.scrollWithAmount(to, false);
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=mbMo8E&v=5)

Comment: That brings me past the bottom of the list and shows empty space until I interact with the list. https://i.imgur.com/4Hfkym0.jpg

Comment: I have updated the answer, tested on both iOS and Android.

Comment: I am still having issues on both platforms. On iOS, it only works if I'm scrolled all the way to the top. If I'm already at the bottom or in the middle it moves me into some whitespace (https://i.imgur.com/TWXT3e7.gif). Android has sort of the opposite issue. If I'm at the top, it won't scroll me all the way to the bottom (I can still see a little blue), but if I'm anywhere else but the top it will work (https://i.imgur.com/4MxBWen.gif).

Comment: That make sense, the intention was to just show how to scroll. You will have to ensure what is the current scroll offset and it's not at top then subtract it from total amount of scroll, basically a couple if conditions.